# Summing result of formula applied to rows

Tags: excel

I have a column of numbers and would like to summarize the result of a formula applied to each row.

For example, if my formula is to square the cell value, in the following table I would like B1 to represent `A1^2 + A2^2 + A3^2`.

```
A    B
-    - 
1    14
2
3
```

Is this possible without creating a column to store the result of the formula for each row before summing (i.e. here, a column containing 1, 4, 9)?

Comment: A little confused.  You ask if its possible to do without creating a column, but in your ie you ask for there to be a column holding 1,4,9.

Comment: I meant that I do not want to create that column.

Comment: you would need VBA to store them if you want some place to have their individual values but not use them.  For the particular formula you have chosen you can go right to the final step and get the some, but the intermediate values will not be kept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your example:

```
=SUM((A1:A3)^2)
```

But here is the key: enter it as an array formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. It will add braces to it and should work.
It should look like this after pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter:

```
{=SUM((A1:A3)^2)}
```

Comment: Replace SUM with SUMPRODUCT and it removes the need for array formula. (`=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A3^2)`).

Comment: Turns out I simplified my problem too much for the question, but I will accept your answer as it applies to what I wrote. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For summing squares of range values, please use this formula `=SUMSQ(A2:A80)`.
So if you have data in Column `A`, put above formula in cell `B2`.

[image]